# Merge two records in same Hive table

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table having these values:
[image]

The objective is to merge two rows whenever first row has end_date=2020-12-14 and second row has the same start_date belonging to the same id. In that case, there will be a merged row with the start_date from the first row and end_date from the second row.

Probable output:
[image]

Comment: dont spam tag  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attempt the following, it solves the problem by left joining to the records to what I believe should be unique.

Then it shifts the joining table to match on T1.end_date = T2.start_date, which should get the records you need in the same row.

Finally, it selects which table the data comes from based on the '2020-12-14' dates, and excludes records where that date is in the start_date column -

```
SELECT
 T1.id,
 T1.name,
 T1.dob,
 T1.start_date as ts_start,
 CASE WHEN T1.end_date = '2020-12-14' THEN T2.end_date ELSE T1.end_date END AS ts_end,
 CASE WHEN T1.end_date = '2020-12-14' THEN T2.is_present ELSE T1.is_present END AS is_present
FROM records T1
LEFT JOIN records T2
 ON T1.id= T2.id AND T1.name= T2.name AND T1.dob = T2.dob AND T1.end_date = T2.start_date
WHERE T1.start_date <> '2020-12-14'
ORDER BY ts_end;
```

I'm not as familiar with HIVE syntax, so you may need to make some edits, but this should have the desired result

Comment: left join would return 3 rows, which is not the correct answer.

Comment: The LEFT JOIN would keep 3 rows after the JOIN yes, but the WHERE T1.start_date <> '2020-12-14' gets rid of the row where start_date in the left table would be the date you're looking to get rid of, bringing it down to two rows.

Comment: Parajit - please review this fiddle and let me know if the result from my query is not exactly what you requested - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0d52aa4656e2ac053a4c4a9afe93f7a0